# Are the resin beads inside old water softeners flammable?

Tags: plumbing, hot-water, water-softener

Our old water softener just broke and released all the resin beads into our hot water heater. I've been draining it but a significant amount of beads went into the drain pan under the hot water heater. I was a bit concerned that if these were flammable, that it would be a hazard to run the how water heater.

-- EDIT

I took them outside and tried to light them. They did blacken after a while and let off a nasty fume, but the stack did not continue to light after the flame was removed. I would still recommend testing your own if anyone else reads this answer with a similar conscern

Comment: Why not just vacuum them out of the drain pan if you're concerned about them?

Comment: I considered it but I think a significant amount of them would be hard to reach. If they are combustable, I would want all of them cleaned up which would be a touch job but doable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly doubt that they are flammable. Water softener beads are made from [zeolites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeolite), which are aluminosilicates (minerals containing aluminium, silicon, and oxygen). They are much more similar to clay than organic resins, although they may be manufactured with a binder of some sort.  If you're really worried that they are flammable, try burning some of them - I'm guessing it would be similar to trying to burn a brick.

Comment: That would be great if that was what we had. I thought that there were different types? I thought they were styrene based?

Answer (score 0):

they are styrene based.  modern resins are a polystyrene bonded with DFB.  zeolites were used at the beginning of the previous century but unless your water softener is 100 years old there's no zeolites in your resin

Comment: And are styrene-based products flammable? Are zeolites? That information would make the answer much better.